# Why Chrome Dev Tools use rgb(204, 154, 129, 0) to produce HSV gradient?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, color-picker

I am making a JS colorpicker and while doing my research I have noticed that Chrome uses `rgb(204, 154, 129, 0)` as a transparent color-stop to produce saturation and value gradients ([link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/devtools/front_end/spectrum.css?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F#64)). Is this value arbitrary and if not, what does it mean?

Comment: Most likely a personal choice of the designer. Why do you think it may have a special meaning?